# how to specify a setup method should only be run once for all tests in mbunit?

Tags: mbunit

so far, the SetUp property specifies the setup method should be run once before every test method, is there a property can specify the setup method should be run only once for all test method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, if one should use such a thing.
But [`FixtureSetupAttribute`](http://www.gallio.org/api/html/T_MbUnit_Framework_FixtureSetUpAttribute.htm) comes close to what you are looking for.